# WooCommerce input field - increment/ decrement field button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add an 'increment/decrement button' to a quantity field in woocommerce on my site - http://tbdemo.tk/aquapark/tickets/

My code in `/woocommerce/templates/global/quantity-input.php` is :

```html
echo "<script>

var i = 0;
    function buttonClick() {
        document.getElementById('inc').value = ++i;
</script>";




if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
?>
<div class="quantity">
<form>
 <input  type="number" id="inc" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
 <input type="button" onclick="buttonClick()" value="Increment Value" />
 </form>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work.

**How can I increment value only on OnFocus field? Not at all input fields....**

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the '}' at the end of the function.

```html
echo "<script>

var i = 0;
    function buttonClick() {
        document.getElementById('inc').value = ++i;
  }
</script>";




if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
?>
<div class="quantity">
<form>
 <input  type="number" id="inc" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
 <input type="button" onclick="buttonClick()" value="Increment Value" />
 </form>
</div>
```